# Hiding members in a C struct

Tags: c, struct, private-members

I've been reading about OOP in C but I never liked how you can't have private data members like you can in C++. But then it came to my mind that you could create 2 structures. One is defined in the header file and the other is defined in the source file.

```
// =========================================
// in somestruct.h
typedef struct {
  int _public_member;
} SomeStruct;

// =========================================
// in somestruct.c

#include "somestruct.h"

typedef struct {
  int _public_member;
  int _private_member;
} SomeStructSource;

SomeStruct *SomeStruct_Create()
{
  SomeStructSource *p = (SomeStructSource *)malloc(sizeof(SomeStructSource));
  p->_private_member = 42;
  return (SomeStruct *)p;
}
```

From here you can just cast one structure to the other.
Is this considered bad practice? Or is it done often?

Comment: Why make it so complicated - If the tool does not do what you need use a different one.

Comment: I think this would violate the object aliasing rules, at least in C99.  I know it would in C++.

Comment: It would be terrible to close this!  Why are people voting close on such a valid question?  Because the forget how to do things in C?

Comment: Don't try to hide things. Just use names for the "private" members that makes it absolutely clear that nobody is to touch them. And if anyone uses them, tell them off. Or change the names to educate them.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Personally, I'd more like this:

```
typedef struct {
  int _public_member;
  /*I know you wont listen, but don't ever touch this member.*/
  int _private_member;
} SomeStructSource;
```

It's C after all, if people want to screw up, they should be allowed to - no need to hide stuff, except:

If what you need is to keep the ABI/API compatible, there's 2 approaches that's more common from what I've seen.

- Don't give your clients access to the struct, give them an opaque handle (a void* with a pretty name), provide init/destroy and accessor functions for everything. This makes sure you can change 
  the structure without even recompiling the clients if you're writing a library.
- provide an opaque handle as part of your struct, which you can allocate however you like. This approach is even used in C++ to provide ABI compatibility.

e.g

```
 struct SomeStruct {
  int member;
  void* internals; //allocate this to your private struct
 };
```

Comment: I find a really bad design allowing the client to access any member of a struct. The whole struct should be private. Access to it's members should be done through getters and setters.

Comment: @fanl doing so in C has a lot of implications, e.g. to hide a struct in that way, it becomes quite hard to allocate it on the stack, or inline as a member of another struct. The easy way out of that is to dynamically allocate the struct and only expose a void* or handle, and while doing so may be ok in some cases, there's many cases where the implications are too big and it will inhibit you from taking advantage of what C provides you.

Comment: IMHO the second example given here should be _the_ answer, just remember to provide a destructor function.

Comment: In performance critical situations, avoid the jump that `void *` implies and just allocate the private data inline - privacy be damned (in this case prefixing an underscore is all you can do).

Comment: Hiding members of a struct can work well with most applications as a form of encapsulation and to break compilation dependencies, however in many constrained (embedded) systems, the use of `malloc` is impractical, and therefore structs will need to be allocated statically or on the stack. Fully hiding the struct makes this difficult (impossible?) so you end up exposing it anyway. And then you have to document it, and then it might as well be explicit.

Comment: @meowsqueak Just because code isn't seen by anyone, doesn't mean that it doesn't need to be documented, otherwise proprietary software development would be one of the best jobs you could ever get in your programming career. Best in a sense that you never have to write documentation... Except until 2 months later when everything is on fire. So, you need to document everything anyway, but doesn't mean you have to explain to others who shouldn't touching it what it is.

Comment: @PurpleIce I agree entirely - what I meant (from memory) is that you have to document it as _part of the API_.

Comment: Your first suggestion is actually a great one. What we do in our company is `struct S { int x; // PRIVATE_FIELD };` and then we have our own C code analyser that checks the comments and if it sees a comment "PRIVATE_FIELD", it prevents users to type `S.x` for that field.

Answer (score 66):

`sizeof(SomeStruct) != sizeof(SomeStructSource)`. This *will* cause someone to find you and murder you someday.

Comment: And any jury would let them go afterwards.

Comment: "Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live." (attributed to Rick Osborne)

Answer (score 32):

You almost have it, but haven't gone far enough.

In the header:

```
struct SomeStruct;
typedef struct SomeStruct *SomeThing;


SomeThing create_some_thing();
destroy_some_thing(SomeThing thing);
int get_public_member_some_thing(SomeThing thing);
void set_public_member_some_thing(SomeThing thing, int value);
```

In the .c:

```
struct SomeStruct {
  int public_member;
  int private_member;
};

SomeThing create_some_thing()
{
    SomeThing thing = malloc(sizeof(*thing));
    thing->public_member = 0;
    thing->private_member = 0;
    return thing;
}

... etc ...
```

The point is, here now consumers have *no* knowledge of the internals of SomeStruct, and you can change it with impunity, adding and removing members at will, even without consumers needing to recompile. They also can't "accidentally" munge members directly, or allocate SomeStruct on the stack. This of course can also be viewed as a disadvantage.

Comment: Some consider using `typedef` to hide pointers to be a bad idea, particularly because it is more obvious that `SomeStruct *` needs to be freed somehow than `SomeThing`, which looks like an ordinary stack variable. Indeed, you can still declare `struct SomeStruct;` and, as long as you don't define it, people will be forced to use `SomeStruct *` pointers without being able to dereference their members, thus having the same effect while not hiding the pointer.

Answer (score 20):

I do not recommend using the public struct pattern. The correct design pattern, for OOP in C, is to provide functions to access every data, never allowing public access to data. The class data should be declared at the source, in order to be private, and be referenced in a forward manner, where `Create` and `Destroy` does allocation and free of the data. In a such way the public/private dilemma won't exist any more.

```
/*********** header.h ***********/
typedef struct sModuleData module_t' 
module_t *Module_Create();
void Module_Destroy(module_t *);
/* Only getters and Setters to access data */
void Module_SetSomething(module_t *);
void Module_GetSomething(module_t *);

/*********** source.c ***********/
struct sModuleData {
    /* private data */
};
module_t *Module_Create()
{
    module_t *inst = (module_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct sModuleData));
    /* ... */
    return inst;
}
void Module_Destroy(module_t *inst)
{
    /* ... */
    free(inst);
}

/* Other functions implementation */
```

In the other side, if you do not want to use Malloc/Free (which can be unnecessary overhead for some situations) I suggest you hide the struct in a private file. Private members will be accessible, but that on user's stake.

```
/*********** privateTypes.h ***********/
/* All private, non forward, datatypes goes here */
struct sModuleData {
    /* private data */
};

/*********** header.h ***********/
#include "privateTypes.h"
typedef struct sModuleData module_t; 
void Module_Init(module_t *);
void Module_Deinit(module_t *);
/* Only getters and Setters to access data */
void Module_SetSomething(module_t *);
void Module_GetSomething(module_t *);

/*********** source.c ***********/
void Module_Init(module_t *inst)
{       
    /* perform initialization on the instance */        
}
void Module_Deinit(module_t *inst)
{
    /* perform deinitialization on the instance */  
}

/*********** main.c ***********/
int main()
{
    module_t mod_instance;
    module_Init(&mod_instance);
    /* and so on */
}
```

Comment: One difficulty with that approach is that it requires the use of malloc/free even in situations where it should be possible for the struct to simply be created as a stack variable and then disappear when the method exits.  Use of malloc/free for things which should have stacking semantics can lead to memory fragmentation if between the creation/destruction other code needs to create persistent objects.  Such problem may be mitigated if one provides a method to use a passed-in block of storage to hold the object, and typedefs an int[] of suitable size for such purpose.

Comment: @supercat True, if you do no want to use malloc/free in your embedded system make the struct private to the programmer, not to the code. I have edited my answer to deal with it.

Comment: That's a reasonable approach.  An approach which would enforce the proper usage even more strongly would be to define a `typedef int module_store_t[20];` and then have a `module_t *Module_CreateIn(module_store_t *p)`.  Code could create an automatic variable of type `module_store_t` and then use `Module_CreateIn` to derive from that that a pointer a newly-initialized module whose lifetime would match that of the auto-variable.

Comment: The second approach does not help in struct encapsulation. Unfortunately, it still allows private struct members to be directly referenced! Please try it in your code.

Comment: Adi, you are right. Unfortunately there is no design pattern able to force the compiler to generate errors if user tries to access data members of the struct when you want to allocate the struct data in the stack, not the heap. This is a short blanket problem and we must address it with common sense. The struct has been defined inside a header named private, so, from now on, user must not access names declared inside these files. It may lead to encapsulation violations, that's why I always stick with the malloc choice (example 1 of the answer).

Comment: As much as I like C for its simplicity, it is so annoying when it comes to applying design patterns. C and design patterns simply are not compatible. And it is really frustrating that, after 40 years of C existence, there is no single technique which would allow you to utilize the best practice coding rules in C. If we ignore the stack allocation issue, ADT technique really could be usable but only if there would be an appropriate malloc implementation which would not cause any fragmentation problems. I am really surprised that there are no Standard C Library implementations <to be continued>

Comment: which are tailored around this issue. I am primarily talking in the context of embedded systems where C is nowadays mostly used and where memory fragmentation represents a big problem. Just to say, I am not satisfied with solutions which use the statically allocated objects instead of malloc. Yeah, one could say that I'm really annoyed with such C 'features' :/

Comment: Agreed Adi. However statically allocated objects might be of good use, since the maximum number of instances of a given struct existing at the same time can be determined with considerable precision. What I usually do in embedded system is to use malloc, if I get allocation fault at some point of the product development, I'll have to overwrite the allocation for each module with the static choice. There will be no implications propagated into the rest of the firmware.

Answer (score 9):

Never do that.  If your API supports anything that takes SomeStruct as a parameter (which I'm expecting it does) then they could allocate one on a stack and pass it in.  You'd get major errors trying to access the private member since the one the compiler allocates for the client class doesn't contain space for it.
The classic way to hide members in a struct is to make it a void*.  It's basically a handle/cookie that only your implementation files know about.  Pretty much every C library does this for private data.

Answer (score 8):

Something similar to the method you've proposed is indeed used sometimes (eg. see the different varities of `struct sockaddr*` in the BSD sockets API), but it's almost impossible to use without violating C99's strict aliasing rules.

You can, however, do it *safely*:

**`somestruct.h`:**

```
struct SomeStructPrivate; /* Opaque type */

typedef struct {
  int _public_member;
  struct SomeStructPrivate *private;
} SomeStruct;
```

**`somestruct.c`:**

```
#include "somestruct.h"

struct SomeStructPrivate {
    int _member;
};

SomeStruct *SomeStruct_Create()
{
    SomeStruct *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    p->private = malloc(sizeof *p->private);
    p->private->_member = 0xWHATEVER;
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd write a hidden structure, and reference it using a pointer in the public structure. For example, your .h could have:

```
typedef struct {
    int a, b;
    void *private;
} public_t;
```

And your .c:

```
typedef struct {
    int c, d;
} private_t;
```

It obviously doesn't protect against pointer arithmetic, and adds a bit of overhead for allocation/deallocation, but I guess it's beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways to do this, like using a `void *` pointer to a private structure in the public struct. The way you are doing it you're fooling the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This approach is valid, useful, standard C.

A slightly different approach, used by sockets API, which was defined by BSD Unix, is the style used for `struct sockaddr`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following workaround:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define C_PRIVATE(T)        struct T##private {
#define C_PRIVATE_END       } private;

#define C_PRIV(x)           ((x).private)
#define C_PRIV_REF(x)       (&(x)->private)

struct T {
    int a;

C_PRIVATE(T)
    int x;
C_PRIVATE_END
};

int main()
{
    struct T  t;
    struct T *tref = &t;

    t.a = 1;
    C_PRIV(t).x = 2;

    printf("t.a = %d\nt.x = %d\n", t.a, C_PRIV(t).x);

    tref->a = 3;
    C_PRIV_REF(tref)->x = 4;

    printf("tref->a = %d\ntref->x = %d\n", tref->a, C_PRIV_REF(tref)->x);

    return 0;
}
```

Result is:

```
t.a = 1
t.x = 2
tref->a = 3
tref->x = 4
```

Comment: interesting... this approach hides declaration of "private" struct, but allows you access private part if you get instance of T struct.

Comment: This will go in my udemy tutorial. Awesome

Answer (score 2):

I found that `bit-field` might be a good solution if you really want to **hide** something.

```c
struct person {
    unsigned long :64;
    char          *name;
    int           age;
};

struct wallet {
    char *currency;
    double balance;
};
```

The first member of struct person is an unnamed bit-ﬁeld. used for a `64-bit pointer` in this case. It's completely hidden and **cannot be accessed by struct variable name**.

Because of the first 64-bit in this struct is unused, so we can use it as a private pointer. We can access this member by its memory address instead of variable name.

```c
void init_person(struct person* p, struct wallet* w) {
    *(unsigned long *)p = (unsigned long)w;
    // now the first 64-bit of person is a pointer of wallet
}

struct wallet* get_wallet(struct person* p) {
    return (struct wallet*)*(unsigned long *)p;
}
```

A small working example, tested on my intel mac:

```c
//
// Created by Rieon Ke on 2020/7/6.
//

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>


#if __x86_64__ || __LP64__
#define PRIVATE_SET(obj, val) *(unsigned long *) obj = (unsigned long) val;
#define PRIVATE_GET(obj, type) (type)*(unsigned long *) obj;
#define PRIVATE_POINTER unsigned long:64
#else
#define PRIVATE_SET(obj, val) *(unsigned int *) obj = (unsigned int) val;
#define PRIVATE_GET(obj, type) (type)*(unsigned int *) obj;
#define PRIVATE_POINTER unsigned int:32
#endif

struct person {
    PRIVATE_POINTER;
    char *name;
    int age;
};

struct wallet {
    char *currency;
    double balance;
};

int main() {

    struct wallet w;
    w.currency = strdup("$$");
    w.balance = 99.9;

    struct person p;
    PRIVATE_SET(&p, &w) //set private member

    p.name = strdup("JOHN");
    p.age = 18;

    struct wallet *pw = PRIVATE_GET(&p, struct wallet*) //get private member

    assert(strcmp(pw->currency, "$$") == 0);
    assert(pw->balance == 99.9);

    free(w.currency);
    free(p.name);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very organized way to do it using macros. This is how I've seen it used in some of the big projects. I will assume the following:

- Header file with the struct
- Source file with access to private fields
- Source file with no access to private fields (the fields exist but are renamed).

Header file:

```c
// You can put this part in a header file
// and share it between multiple header files in your project
#ifndef ALLOW_PRIVATE_ACCESS
#define PRIVATE(T) private_##T
#else
#define PRIVATE(T) T
#endif
#define PUBLIC(T) T

typedef struct {
  int PRIVATE(m1); // private member
  int PUBLIC(m2); // public member
} mystruct;

mystruct *mystruct_create(void);
int mystruct_get_m1(mystruct *t);
```

Source file with access to private fields:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ALLOW_PRIVATE_ACCESS
#include "mystruct.h"

mystruct *mystruct_create(void) {
  mystruct *p = (mystruct *)malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
  p->m1 = 42; // works (private)
  p->m2 = 34; // works (public)
  return (mystruct *)p;
}

int mystruct_get_m1(mystruct *t) {
    return t->m1; // works (private)
}
```

Source file with no access to private fields:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mystruct.h"

int main() {
    mystruct *t = mystruct_create();
    printf("t->m1 = %d\n", t->m1); // error (private)
    printf("t->m1 = %d\n", mystruct_get_m1(t)); // works (using function)
    printf("t->m2 = %d\n", t->m2); // works (public)
    free(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to provide only the prototype of the internal struct and then declare the definition in the .c file. Very useful to show C interface and use C++ behind.

.h :

```
struct internal;

struct foo {
   int public_field;
   struct internal *_internal;
};
```

.c :

```
struct internal {
    int private_field; // could be a C++ class
};
```

Note: In that case, the variable have to be a pointer because the compiler is unable to know the size of the internal struct.

Answer (score 1):

Related, though not exactly hiding.

Is to conditionally deprecate members.

Note that this works for GCC/Clang, but MSVC and other compilers can deprecate too,
so its possible to come up with a more portable version.

If you build with fairly strict warnings, or warnings as errors, this at least avoids accidental use.

```
// =========================================
// in somestruct.h

#ifdef _IS_SOMESTRUCT_C
#  if defined(__GNUC__)
#    define HIDE_MEMBER __attribute__((deprecated))
#  else
#    define HIDE_MEMBER  /* no hiding! */
#  endif
#else
#  define HIDE_MEMBER
#endif

typedef struct {
  int _public_member;
  int _private_member  HIDE_MEMBER;
} SomeStruct;

#undef HIDE_MEMBER


// =========================================
// in somestruct.c
#define _IS_SOMESTRUCT_C
#include "somestruct.h"

SomeStruct *SomeStruct_Create()
{
  SomeStructSource *p = (SomeStructSource *)malloc(sizeof(SomeStructSource));
  p->_private_member = 42;
  return (SomeStruct *)p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very private, given that the calling code can cast back to a `(SomeStructSource *)`.  Also, what happens when you want to add another public member?  You'll have to break binary compatibility.

EDIT: I missed that it was in a .c file, but there really is nothing stopping a client from copying it out, or possibly even `#include`ing the .c file directly.

Comment: This is why SomeStructSource is defined in the source file.

Comment: Only so if you publish SomeStructSource.  A C++ object pointer is similar, one could use offsetof() and pointer maths to get to the private members.

Answer (score 0):

An anonymous struct can be of use here.

```
#ifndef MYSTRUCT_H
#define MYSTRUCT_H

typedef struct {
  int i;
  struct {
    int j;
  } MYSTRUCT_PRIVATE;

  // NOTE: Avoid putting public members after private
  int k;
} MyStruct;

void test_mystruct();

#endif
```

In any file that should have access to the private members, define `MYSTRUCT_PRIVATE` as an empty token before including this header. In those files, the private members are in an anonymous struct and can be accessed using `m.j`, but in all other places they can only be accessed using `m.MYSTRUCT_PRIVATE.j`.

```
#define MYSTRUCT_PRIVATE
#include "mystruct.h"

void test_mystruct() {
  // Can access .j without MYSTRUCT_PRIVATE in both
  // initializer and dot operator.
  MyStruct m = { .i = 10, .j = 20, .k = 30 };
  m.j = 20;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mystruct.h"

int main() {
  // You can declare structs and, if you jump through
  // a small hoop, access private members
  MyStruct m = { .i = 10, .k = 30 };
  m.MYSTRUCT_PRIVATE.j = 20;

  // This will not work
  //MyStruct m2 = { .i = 10, .j = 20, .k = 30 };

  // But this WILL work, be careful
  MyStruct m3 = { 10, 20, 30 };

  test_mystruct();

  return 0;
}
```

I do not recommend putting public members after private members. Initializing a struct without member designators, such as with `{ 10, 20, 30 }` can still initialize private members. If the number of private members changes, this will also silently break all initializers without member designators. It's probably best to always use member designators to avoid this.

You must design your structs, and especially the private members, to be zero initialized since there are no automatic constructors as in C++. As long as the members are initialized to 0 then they won't be left in an invalid state even without an initialization function. Barring a member designator initialization, initializing to simply `{ 0 }` should be designed to be safe.

The only downside I've found is that this does mess with things like debuggers and code completion, they typically don't like it when one type has one set of members in one file, and a different set in another file.