# How to expose C struct size without exposing its type?

Tags: c

I have the following in C (not C++!):

```
module.c
    struct Private {...};
    void foo(void* private, int param) {...}

module.h
    #define PRIVATE_SIZE ???;
    void foo(void* private, int param);

main.c
    char m1[PRIVATE_SIZE];
    char m2[PRIVATE_SIZE];

    int main()
    {
        foo(m1, 10);
        foo(m2, 20);
    }
```

How can I expose sizeof(Private) at compile time so that application can ***statically*** allocate its storage without exposing Private type?

Note, this is a very limited embedded system and dynamic allocation is not available.

Comment: Why do you need it for static allocation? If you need an init function anyway, why not dynamically allocate the memory in that function as well?

Comment: Sounds like you can't: to determine the size you need to know all its membes; to hide its members means you can't determine the size.

Comment: This looks like an information hiding pattern. Look at this code example, maybe it can help you: https://github.com/adamtornhill/PatternsInC/tree/master/1_FirstClassADT

Comment: You can define a (const) size_t variable in module.c which is initialized with `sizeof(Private)` (which is known there) and expose it for public use through a declaration in module.h. [Actually, the variable would probably be a static variable in a function which returns its value; this avoids static intialization order issues.] As an aside, I also wonder whether you could forward-declare Private and have a better type check e.g. with the parameter for `Init()`.

Comment: You shouldn't be overlooking alignment requirements since you are at the business of exposing size only.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider There are no static initialization order issues in C. Also, moving static variables into functions doesn't affect initialization order.

Comment: @Gerhardh I'm running on embedded system with tens of kilobytes of memory

Comment: @A.R.C Unfortunately, in example the object allocates itself dynamically, I can only use static allocation which is why my module must rely on the application to allocate one or more private objects.

Comment: You can replace the dynamic allocation in the example with a static object in the .c file. The information what types of information is stored inside the struct is still hiddent to the outside.

Comment: @melpomene Are you saying that there is a strict ordering of the initialization of static variables in different translation units in C? So the [problem existing in C++](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) does not exist in C?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I'm saying there are no dependencies between static variables, so the order doesn't matter.

Comment: "limited embedded system and dynamic allocation is not available." --> what system/compiler is that?

Comment: What problem do you try to solve with information hiding? What do you expect to gain with it? If not much, then just move your type definition to header.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't expose the size of the struct to the caller, because that breaks the whole purpose of having private encapsulation in the first place. Allocation of your private data is no business of the caller. Also, avoid using `void*` because they complete lack type safety.

This is how you write private encapsulation in C:

- In module.h, forward declare an incomplete type `typedef struct module module;`.
- In module.c, place the struct definition of this struct. it will only be visible to module.c and not to the caller. This is known as *opaque types*.
- The caller can only allocate pointers to this struct, never allocate objects.
- Caller code might look like:

  ```
  #include "module.h"
  ...
  module* m;
  result = module_init(&m)
  ```
- And the `module_init` function acts as a "constructor", declared in module.h and defined in module.c:

  ```
  bool module_init (module** obj)
  {
    module* m = malloc(sizeof *m);
    ...
    m->something = ...; // init private variables if applicable

    *obj = m;
    return true;
  }
  ```
- If the caller does need to know the size of the objects, it would only be for the purpose of hard copy etc. If there's a need for that, provide a copy function which encapsulates the allocation and copy ("copy constructor"), for example:

  ```
  result module_copy (module** dst, const module* src);
  ```

Edit:

Please note that the manner of allocation is a separate issue. You don't have to use dynamic allocation for the above design. In embedded systems for example, it is common to use static memory pools instead. See [Static allocation of opaque data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440476/static-allocation-of-opaque-data-types)

Comment: Please, see my @A.R.C comment in the question

Comment: @jackhab Added a note at the bottom of the answer regarding that. In particular, see the answer by Clifford in the linked post.

Answer (score 3):

You can't allocate size for a struct such as this because it isn't known at compile time.  Even if you did know the size at run time, you'd still have issues due to alignment.

There is a possible solution which involves defining a separate structure that has the same size and alignment requirements as the private struct.

For example:

module.h:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

struct Public {
    uint64_t opaque1;
    uint64_t opaque2;
    uint64_t opaque3;
};

void init(struct Public *p);
```

module.c:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdalign.h>
#include "module.h"

struct Private {
    int a;
    double b;
    float c;
};

static_assert(sizeof(struct Private)==sizeof(struct Public), "sizes differ");
static_assert(alignof(struct Private)==alignof(struct Public), "alignments differ");

void init(struct Public *p)
{
    struct Private *pr = (struct Private *)p;
    pr->a = 2;
    pr->b = 2.5;
    pr->c = 2.4f;
}
```

The `Public` and `Private` structs are guaranteed to have the same size, and the alignment *should* be the same.  There is the possibility of the user writing the the "opaque" fields of the public struct, in which case you could have aliasing issues regarding effective types, but if the user can be trusted to do that then this should work.

---

Another, more robust option, is if you have some idea of the maximum number of objects you want to support.  If that's the case, you can have a static array of these objects in your implementation file, and the init function would return a pointer to one of the objects in this list.  Then you'd have a related cleanup function that would free the instance.

For example:

module.c:

```
struct Private {
    int a;
    double b;
    float c;
};

struct PrivateAllocator {
    struct Private obj;
    int used;
};

struct PrivateAllocator list[5] = {
    { { 0, 0, 0}, 0 },
    { { 0, 0, 0}, 0 },
    { { 0, 0, 0}, 0 },
    { { 0, 0, 0}, 0 },
    { { 0, 0, 0}, 0 }
};

struct Private *private_init()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        if (!list[i].used) {
            list[i].used = 1;
            return &list[i].obj;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void private_free(struct Private *p)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        if (&list[i].obj == p) {
            list[i].used = 0;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, dbush! Can you provide and example of alignment problem which can arise here?

Comment: @jackhab In the above example, `struct Private` would typically have an alignment requirement of 8.  If you just created a `char` array to layer the struct on top of, that array might not have that alignment.  On some systems, misalignment can cause inefficient code to be generated or even a memory fault.

Comment: Yes you may add padding variables to fill up the space. But anyway that static-assert is very effective.

Answer (score 1):

In conforming C code you can't create a static instance of an arbitrary unknown type even if you know its size at compile time (not even if you know the alignment).

Let's say you try doing it anyway. How would you do it, given the size in a macro or enum `PRIVATE_SIZE`?

```
unsigned char obj[PRIVATE_SIZE];
```

And then you'd pass `(void*)obj` to wherever its needed, right?
Well, this breaks the aliasing rules. While you can legally access any individual char/byte in any object, you can't do it the other way around saying that those chars are not chars, they are just storage behind other types. That is, you can't legally have a `short int` superimposed on top of, say, `obj[2]` and `obj[3]` through smarty-pants casts (e.g. `((struct Private*)obj)->my_short = 2;`). The only legal way to do something like this would be through `memcpy()`, e.g. `memcpy(&temp, obj, sizeof temp);` and then back after the modification. Or you'd need to work with individual chars of `obj[]`.

There are two possible ways to sort of do it. One is described in another answer, basically define the instance where the type is known, but only let the outside world have a pointer to it.

Another, very similar, define it in assembly code and, again, let the outside world have a pointer to it. The "beauty" of the assembly way is that you really only need a name, an alignment and a size to allocate space for a named object.

And if you put the instances into a special data section (see the gcc's section attribute and the linker scripts), you may even have all of the instances in the same place (think, array) and even find out their cumulative size and therefore count.

Yet another thing to do while not explicitly violating any C rules is to still use this `unsigned char obj[PRIVATE_SIZE]` trick, but launder it by passing it unchanged through an assembly function that the C compiler can't look into, e.g. something like

```
// struct Private* launder(unsigned char*);
.text
.globl launder
launder:
    move %first_param_reg, %return_reg
    ret
```

But you'll really need to change `unsigned char obj[PRIVATE_SIZE]` to something that would have proper alignment on your architecture, e.g. `double obj[PRIVATE_SIZE / sizeof(double)]` (or the same with `long long` if you like that way better).

As for `PRIVATE_SIZE`, you can have a check at compile time that it matches the size of the type, e.g.

```
#include "mod.h" // mod.h defines PRIVATE_SIZE
struct Private { ... };
extern char StAtIcAsSeRt[sizeof(struct Private) == PRIVATE_SIZE];
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to expose C struct size without exposing its type?

If able to compromise a bit:  (statically --> `main()` local)
with *variable length arrays* (C99), use a helper function and put the array in `main()`.

```
module.h
  size_t foo_size(void);

main.c
  int main() {
    char m1[foo_size()];
    foo(m1, 10);
  }
```

Additional work needed to account for alignment issues.

Consider relaxing your goal as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54782482/2410359).

Answer (score 0):

C99 allowes you to use **variable length array.**

private.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern const size_t size;
```

private.c:

```
#include "private.h"
struct Private {
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
};

const size_t size = sizeof(struct Private);
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "private.h"
int main(void) {
        char m1[size]; //variable length array
        printf("Size of m1 = %ld\n", sizeof(m1));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my compiler (Microchip XC8) does not support VLAs