# const and destruction responsibility in C

Tags: c, constants

Suppose I have a first struct type `a_t` and a second struct type `b_t`, and one of the fields of `b_t` is a pointer to an instance of `a_t`. I have creation and destruction functions:

```
b_t* b_t_create(a_t* a_t_instance) {
   b_t_instance = (b_t*) malloc(sizeof(b_t));
   b_t_instance.a_t_instance = a_t_instance;
   return b_t_instance;
}

void b_t_destruct(b_t* b_t_instance) {
   free(b_t_instance->a_t_instance);
   free(b_t_instance);
}
```

Thus destruction responsibility migrates from `a_t` to `b_t`... My question is; is it advisable to rewrite the first function with a `const` and de-`const` cast as follows?

```
b_t* b_t_create(const a_t* a_t_instance) {
   b_t_instance = (b_t*) malloc(sizeof(b_t));
   b_t_instance.a_t_instance = (a_t*) a_t_instance;
   return b_t_instance;
}
```

On first look, it seems reasonable because the function itself does not touch upon `a_t_instance`. On the other hand, it secretly gives it in the hands of something that will later on destruct it, and thus, in fact not so secretly, we have a de-`const` cast inside, because the struct field `a_t_instance` is of type `a_t*`, in view of that inevitable destruction...

Comment: Why would you lie to the caller? No, don't use the `const`.

Comment: @ikegami OK, so you mean that, in general, if I de`const` a function's parameter by cast in the function body, it is considered as modification, and hence the parameter should not be put as const at the first place?

Comment: You need something modifiable. Don't lie and say otherwise. Why would you want to!?

Comment: @ikegami Well, my `a_t` is planned to be not modified, just read, once it was created, except when it is destructed... I believe it is a common case...

Comment: So you need something modifiable, like I said.

Comment: @ikegami OK, thank you

Comment: OT: Don't cast the return from `malloc()`. It'll get you in trouble one day. Also,  recommend using the _object_, not the _type_ as parameter to `sizeof`. Eg: `b_t *p = malloc( sizeof *p );` Again, less chance for oversight during modifications introducing a bug.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thanks for the second point. For the first one, you mean just drop the cast and let the compiler cast (void *) to whatever I need automatically?

Comment: Any pointer can be implicitly converted to a `void*` (and vice-versa). /// As for the second point, it doesn't actually help; it only shifts the problem. If you really want to improve that, use a type-safe macro such as `#define MALLOC(t, n) ( (t*)malloc(sizeof(t) * n) )` and `b_t *p = MALLOC( b_t, 1 );`

Comment: @ikegami well, if I will eventually use free() on it, and free accepts a pointer-to-modifiable, then I guess it should be a modifiable variable...

Comment: @Sasha Yes. It's too easy for a human to _cast_ to the wrong type, and then change the type of the variable to silence the warning... The compiler can handle it. Less code means fewer chances for bugs to be written into the code.

Comment: @Sasha, yeah, I got confused for a second. Comment already deleted.

Comment: Please read about [container_of](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/design-patterns.txt) pattern to say it could simplify your code and help you avoid using pointless dynamic allocations.

Comment: If you forget to include `stdlib.h` and use `malloc` you will get some warning about converting an inteter to a pointer if you don't use a cast. If you use a cast, the compiler must assume you know what you are doing and happily converts the integer (possibly of smaller size) to your pointer. That way you avoid error detection by the compiler.

Comment: Is there a reason why `a_t` is not a proper member of the `b_t` struct (the first member)? Because that's how you most correctly implement inheritance in C. If you are doing something else, you need to have very good reasons for it.

Comment: @Lundin Oh, ok, I see, I will think about it... I am trying to converge to a correct idiomatic usage of C.

Comment: @Sasha I just posted an answer that might give some insights of that - in particular of "opaque types" which is the means through we do (admittedly cumbersome) OO design in C. What we can't do in C compared to languages with built-in OO support is "RAII" - that is, automatic constructor/destructor calls. So that always has to be a manual call, but C programmers are used to that.

Comment: Shouldn't `void b_t_create(a_t* a_t_instance)` be `b_t* b_t_create(a_t* a_t_instance)`?

Comment: @IanAbbott Oh, sure, thanks, edited.

Comment: If you need to cast away the `const`-ness, that's usually a good sign that it shouldn't have been `const` in the first place. Sometimes there are situations where you need to break this heuristic rule, but this does not seem like one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C idiom, when a functions receives a pointer to a dynamic object, it can *borrow* it, meaning that it will use it, but the caller will still be responsible for later destruction, or *steal* it and take ownership of the object. In that latter case, the caller is no longer responsible for later destruction. Borrowing in the more common use case, and stealing shall be documented.

Here the `b_t_create` function *steals* the pointer. You normally use const to say that the object will not be changed (both to the compiler and to the user of the function). As the object is now intended to later be deleted at `b_t` destruction *without any action on the object itself*, you cannot say that is left unchanged. Hence you should not declare it const.

Comment: Thanks, very useful answer! Just a minor point, I didn't understand the logic of your "As [...] without any action on the object itself [...]"... if there was an action, it would make things even worse, so even more reason to not const, no?

Comment: I meant that the `a_t` object is deleted without a direct call form the caller code to any function using it. Sorry if I was not clear, but English is not my first language...

Answer (score 1):

The general rule of thumb is that every module is responsible for providing the means to clean up its own mess. If you have a type `a_t` which does something like dynamic allocation internally, then `a_t` must provide a clean-up function as part of its API. This is how you most commonly implement "opaque types" ([How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888)), where the caller is not allowed to manually allocate an instance of the struct.

However, if the caller *is* able to allocate an instance of `a_t` in the manner that the caller decides, then the caller is responsible for cleaning that up.

You case *seems* to be the latter...?

Anyway, there are two correct ways to design all of this depending on if the `a_t` -> `b_t` relation is *inheritance* or if `b_t` is merely *a user* of `a_t`.

**Inheritance:**

- `a_t` is an opaque type.
- `a_t` either allocates itself internally or uses a passed allocator function -  [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667901/584518).
- `a_t` provides a constructor and destructor as part of its API.
- `b_t` is an opaque type and its definition looks like this:

  ```c
  struct b_t {
    a_t parent;
    ...
  };
  ```
- `b_t` has access to `a_t`'s internals - this can be done in several ways. For example by having `a_t.c` include a header `a_t_private.h` containing the struct definition. `b_t.c` may then include `a_t_private.h`.

The advantage of having the parent declared as a proper member is that it enables type compatibility and polymorphism both. C has a rule that a pointer to struct can always safely be cast to a pointer to the struct's first member and vice versa. So it will be possible for the caller to cast a `b_t*` to a `a_t*` or the other way around.

Additionally, allocating all memory together in one go gives better performance.

---

**b_t is a user of a_t:**

- `b_t` is optionally an opaque type.
- `b_t` has no access to `a_t` internals.
- `b_t` allocates/frees `a_t` through the API provided by `a_t`. It does not and cannot use raw `malloc`/`free` calls since `a_t` is opaque.
- Assuming that `a_t` may get modified internally during use, then you cannot pass a `const a_t*` to `b_t`'s constructor.
- Notably there is nothing called "de-const cast" in C. Your code `... = (a_t*) a_t_instance` is rather called "an undefined behavior bug". You shouldn't have used `const` to begin with here.

Comment: Very useful, thank you very much for taking the time to write that!