# MISRA C advises against malloc, does this mean calloc is far more secure?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, misra

I have used C for a few years but only recently made a serious effort to understand undefined behaviour and the pitfalls of C memory leaks etc. This is because now I use calloc several times in some code. The MISRA C recommendation is: *Avoiding using functions and constructs that are prone to failure, for example, malloc may fail.*
I presume this means memory allocation could be a problem, does this mean calloc is secure?
If not would this be advisable:

```
uint32_t *array;
        array = calloc(length, 32);
```

or is it just window dressing?

Thank you for any advice, I really want to avoid bad practise.

Comment: I don't know the reasoning behind "`malloc` can fail", as *many* functions "can fail". Including `calloc`. I don't think the failures of `malloc` are related to the setting of memory or not, but rather that `malloc` can fail and return a null pointer, which needs to be checked for even when using `calloc` or any other function that allocates memory.

Comment: And in C, there's really no other suitable way to allocate memory dynamically from the OS. In C you *must* use `malloc` (or `calloc`, or OS-specific function, etc.) in any kind of complex program, often there's just no other way around it.

Comment: Thus MISRA's intent -- dynamic memory allocation is a bad thing.  It grudgingly admits that you can allocate memory to accommodate configuration-based data; but you cannot free or resize it.   MISRA also disavows itself of two's compliment arithmetic, deeming its nuances too difficult for mere mortals.   Confirmation bias supported by misapplied rational plays a big role in their work.

Comment: No since in practice most implementation of `calloc` are calling `malloc` (or an equivalent internal function)

Comment: On top of the answers and comments, reading the platform specific advice usually helps. QNX has a good introduction to _"Working with Memory"_. If QNX is not your target, you'll probably find something similar for your platform.

Comment: One issue that may lead you to favour `calloc` is that your program may be more robust without garbage values in uninitialized memory. Let's say you use `malloc` and you do not initialize properly. Sometimes uninitializes memory is 0,  and the program works fine. But later on, your program will encounter garbage and, say, your null termination test fails! Then the program crashes in production. It's better to have reproducible initial states for debugging, so `calloc` may be better. In the end, it's a matter of discipline.

Comment: @Surge Using `calloc` is often "lazy" and hides real problems, like reading uninitialized memory. If what's being initialized are (compositions of) fundamental types only and "0"-ish is what's wanted, then fine, but that's for allocations made at the lowest level only.

Comment: @mevets MISRA actually just inherited the ban of malloc claim from its normative safety standards such as IEC 61508. There are at least ten different safety standards for diverse applications banning dynamic allocation, it's nothing new or unique to MISRA. So I think the confirmation bias "MISRA is bad" is coming from you here...

Answer (score 2):

Any call can fail. If there is no memory to allocate, malloc will return null. If you don't check this return value, and provide suitable handling logic for an out of memory event, your program may crash. Often the only thing you can do is provide a message to the user about the situation.

If you are in a safety critical enviroment, where a software crash could lead to a car crash, this is very bad, hence for any loop involving the real time operation of an automobile, dynamic memory allocation is best avoided, as would be potential recursion.

window dressing in the form of calloc is not going to make any difference.

Comment: "*Any call can fail*" -- yes and no.  The MISRA issue is about functions with *defined* failure modes, which is not all of them.  Of those, MISRA is concerned about functions that are *prone* to fail, which is somewhat ambiguous, but much fewer than all functions.

Comment: "`malloc` will return null" -- only if your OS is not in the habit of [overcommitting memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment).

Answer (score 2):

> is it just window dressing?

Indeed it is. It doesn't matter if you use `malloc` or `calloc` (which does the same as `malloc` + initialization).

The key is checking the return value.

MISRA:

> Avoiding using functions and constructs that are prone to failure

Taken out of context, this leaves someone who wants to do dynamic memory allocation with no other choice than to

1. Disregard the MISRA advice and just make sure every allocation is checked.
2. Make a big static allocation at program startup and use that as the only memory pool in the entire program. Provide proof that your program will never exceed the allocation made.

Comment: "Make a big static allocation at program startup": The programme I am working on reads text from a file. I have tested it up 50,000,000 characters but I will probably only need 48,000 at the most. An array of 100,000 should easily be enough but would using 48,000 elements of an array 50,000,000 elements long just introduce another set of problems?

Comment: @IanStewart Ok. Does it need to be available at all times or would reading the file every time be an alternative?

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I think that's the solution, to read the file in chunks - the complete text is never needed at once. Also the 50,000,000 characters would never, ever be needed - it was just a way of testing the code as I had had problems in the beginning, when I could not get it to read more than 1047 characters. I will see how much text is usually needed and use a static allocation. Then deal with exceptions when they are required - probably rarely, maybe never.

Answer (score 1):

> The MISRA C recommendation is: *Avoiding using functions and constructs that are prone to failure, for example, malloc may fail.*
> I presume this means memory allocation could be a problem, does this mean calloc is secure?

MISRA C:2012 (and continued into :2023) is very clear:

- Directive D.4.12 - Dynamic memory allocation shall not be used

And if that is not enough:

- Rule 21.3 - The memory allocation and deallocation functions of `<stdlib.h>` shall not be used

In Rule 21.3, the amplification even lists the functions:

- `calloc`, `malloc`, `realloc`, `aligned_alloc` and `free`

So the simple answer to your question is: **No, `calloc` is not OK** if you wish to be MISRA C compliant.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and listing the functions - invaluable, especially as they are from the chairman. From this invaluable discussion, I have now removed all dynamic memory allocation from my code. Good practise and safe code is something I really want to learn correctly and is usually the reason I ask questions on this forum.

Comment: A related question; does that mean it would be better to remove <stdlib.h> altogether and use <stdint> when uint32_t is needed? Except sometimes I need exit() of course.

Comment: I would advise to use `<stdint.h>` directly... while many features of `<stdlib.h>` are restricted by MISRA C, not all of it is - so there is no outright restriction on `<stdlib.h>` unlike some of the other header files (although some of those are subject to review)

Answer (score 0):

MISRA C is surprisingly brief when condemning malloc + friends. Dynamic allocation is a cardinal sin in all manner of safety-related applications and every other somewhat related standard out there bans it as well (IEC61508 + and the other "SIL" ones (trains, household appliances etc), ISO 26262, DO178, the JSF and NASA standards etc etc).

The potential error returned by `malloc` caused by running out of memory is probably the least problem with that function - because if you are running out of memory it means your whole program design is broken and that's no fault of malloc as such.

This Codidact post answers your question in detail, including the numerous severe problems with malloc and dynamic allocation in embedded systems:
[Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121)

As for what can be used instead, safety-related applications use static sized buffers. Memory pools could be acceptable in some scenarios too, long as you have the error checking/handling there, check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667901/584518).

Comment: Noone asked a question to which this fine information would be an answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo "malloc + friends" meaning malloc + calloc + realloc, I thought that was obvious.