# Efficient solutions for vector type definitions and data protection in C

Tags: c, pointers, misra

How can I efficiently define custom types for dynamic arrays in C, ensuring const qualification for vectors data types without resorting to duplicate structures with constant methods and make_const functions? I am currently using the following implementation:

```c
typedef struct
{
    int *             data;
    unsigned long int len;
    unsigned long int size;
} VecInt;

typedef struct
{
    const int *       data;
    unsigned long int len;
    unsigned long int size;
} CVecInt;

CVecInt make_const_VecInt ( VecInt * src )
{
    return (CVecInt) { .data = src->data, .len = src->len, .size = src->size };
}
```

Is there a more efficient or elegant solution to achieve the desired const qualification for the vector data types in C?

I want to avoid type casting due to potential risks associated with misalignment.

Note: MISRA-C 2012 drove this design, and solutions should at least take this code standard under consideration.

Clarification after reading the answers:

The application doesn't require dynamic reallocation. The purpose of working with these structures is to avoid messing with the lengths or arrays passed between functions.

Clarification, interfaces:

The software needs to store large files of signals and process them. The way to do it is always using interfaces like this:

```
CVecInt build_something ( VecInt * dst , CVecInt src );
```

Where `dst` comes from pre-allocated array like this:

```
static int palloc_signal [ SIZE ] = { 0 };
VecInt signal = { .data = palloc_signal , .len = 0 , .size = SIZE };
```

The build function layout is always like this:

```
CVecInt build_something ( VecInt * dst , CVecInt src )
{
    /* maths on src and writes to dst */

    return make_const_VecInt(dst);
}
```

Comment: Do you really need a separate struct for `const`? if your data is supposed to be immutable, return a `const VecInt*` where applicable.

Comment: _Side note:_ You may want `size_t` instead of `unsigned long`

Comment: @CraigEstey, thanks for the advice, I did not use it here just to avoid having dependencies in the example.

@TedLyngmo As far as I know, this won't trigger any compiler error If a developer attempts to modify any data item, e.g.,  ```example->data[0]```

Comment: @Sam Oh, ok, I see what you mean. You could hide the data and only allow access to it via your functions though.

Comment: If you use flexible arrays like in gulpr's answer then `example->data[0] = ...;` would generate a compilation error (if `example` is a `const*`).

Comment: @TedLyngmo, that's true, and also the use of dynamic memory will not be compliant with my software standard, but I get the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MISRA C encourages the use of "opaque types" (Dir 4.8), so that's usually the way to go.

That is, your header will have a forward declaration:

```
typedef struct VecInt VecInt;
```

But the struct definition is only placed in the C file. That way the caller won't know anything of the struct members nor can they access them directly. Your class/ADT will have to provide the interface in form of setters/getters etc.

I recommend to use the above form and not to do like in the MISRA example by hiding a pointer behind a typedef. The caller will be dealing with pointers so you might as well let them know that, or they'll think they can copy the objects with assignment and get a hard copy, or start passing them by reference although they are pointers already.

In order to deal with allocation and since you can't use `malloc`, you need to design a simple memory pool. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667901/584518). In the link, a centralized memory pool is used and an allocator function is passed as callback to the constructor of the opaque type. The alternative is to place the memory pool inside your ADT.

Finally, you should seriously consider if you even need to this amount of abstraction for plain arrays. In the kind of applications where you usually encounter MISRA C, "keep it simple" is the key. And everything needs to be deterministic, so the presence of `realloc`-like behavior is usually a sign of bad design.

Comment: I agree with you. I might not have explained the purpose of these structures clearly in my previous response; it's unrelated to reallocations.

Memory is set privately from some given input data, and consumers access resulted data directly through these read-only structures, containing length and maximum size (robustness redundancy). The application needs to statically pre-allocate 5Gb of named arrays, so I share your view that using getters and setters in an Abstract Data Type (ADT) could be less efficient and cumbersome.

Comment: @Sam What you describe rather sounds like a getter function. 5Gb was a typo, or...?

Comment: no it is not a typo. The software needs to store large files of signals and process them. I added a last note to my original question to describe it. And this is the rational to need the make_const functions.

Comment: @Sam That is a very strange combination together with MISRA C requirements. Some sort of 3D model or game? Space shuttle? :) But well, it can be done if you have a 64 bit address bus and `size_t` is large enough. I can be probably be done in painful ways with 32 bit address bus too, utilizing some memory extension mechanism supported by the system.

Comment: Yes, I believe it is a really particular combination. It is an on-ground equipment following DO-278A which process large amounts of data, and thankfully as you guess it is 64bit bus address.

Comment: @Sam Aah, I see, makes sense. Can't say I know it, although I designed a fieldbus control system used by airplane washing machines at one point. Back then there was lots of focus on EMC and not so much on software.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a more efficient or elegant solution to achieve the desired
> const qualification for the vector data types in C?

Yes, do not expose the `struct` to the library user. Only allow the access by functions. Also, I would use flexible array members.

```c
typedef struct
{
    size_t len;
    size_t size;
    int data[];
} VecInt;


VecInt *create(size_t size)
{
    VecInt *v = malloc(sizeof(*v) + size * sizeof(v -> data[0]));
    if(v)
    {
        v -> len = 0;
        v -> size = size;
    }
    return v;
}

size_t getsize(const void *v)
{
    const VecInt *vi = v;
    return vi ? vi -> size : 0;
}

VecInt *resize(VecInt *v, size_t newsize)
{
    v = realloc(v, sizeof(*v) + newsize * sizeof(v -> data[0]));
    if(v)
    {
        v -> size = newsize;
    }
    return v;
}


 /* etc */
```

Comment: I appreciate your proposal. Maybe some similar approach using ADT in the sense of @DavidRanieri, it is the cleanest solution, but I discarded it because my team was not prepared to work with ADT.

Comment: Using a FAM here means you can't change the capacity of the vector after allocating it. May or may not matter depending on what OP is doing.

Comment: @Shawn - nonsense - see in the answer how to archive it

Comment: @gulpr Note that reallocating the entire `struct` does invalidate all other pointers to any one vector instance.

Comment: What Andrew said. Not to mention `x = realloc(x, new_size);` has issues itself when `realloc()` returns a null pointer.

Comment: @Shawn no - it does not have issues in this case as `v` is a **local** variable and it does not modify the caller's one. You've hear that temporary variable should be used, but I do not think that you really understand why and when it is important. My code **does not** leak any memory if the `realloc` failed

Comment: You can no longer access it in the `resize()` function, and if it's called as `blah = resize(blah, new_size)` as seems natural at first glance you get the same issue as with realloc and a memory leak. Would be less error prone to take a pointer to a pointer and return a boolean to indicate success or failure (as would `realloc()`; it's fundamentally a bad design the way it is), but that still has the same problem with invalidating any other pointers to the struct.

Comment: @Shawn - if it fails it is not accessed only NULL is returned. Your comments show that you simply do not understand what the code does. I will not continue the discussion as it  makes no sense. Andrew's comment has the same quality. FAMs were introduced exactly for this reason.

Comment: Better to use `struct VecInt` rather than `void *` and just make the struct an opaque type (so just `typedef struct VecInt VecInt;` in the header file)