# Segmentation fault in cast struct in c

Tags: c, oop, struct, segmentation-fault

In an attempt to encapsulate struct members (in a similar way as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672015/hiding-members-in-a-c-struct) question), I created the code below.

In the code below, I have a c-struct, which contains methods to access members of the struct which are hidden (by being cast into a struct otherwise the same but without the hidden properties)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct class {
    int publicValue;
    int (*getPV)();
    void (*setPV)(int newPV);
} class;

typedef struct classSource {
    int publicValue;
    int apv;
    int (*getPV)();
    void (*setPV)(int newPV);
    int PV;
} classSource;

class class_init() {
    classSource cs;
    cs.publicValue = 15;
    cs.PV = 8;
    int class_getPV() {
        return cs.PV;
    };
    void class_setPV(int x) {
        cs.PV = x;
    };
    cs.getPV = class_getPV;
    cs.setPV = class_setPV;
    class *c = (class*)(&cs);
    return *c;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    class c = class_init();
    c.setPV(3452);
    printf("%d", c.publicValue);
    printf("%d", c.getPV());
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I get a segmentation fault error. However, I noticed that if I comment out certain lines of code, it (seems) to work okay:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct class {
    int publicValue;
    int (*getPV)();
    void (*setPV)(int newPV);
} class;

typedef struct classSource {
    int publicValue;
    int apv;
    int (*getPV)();
    void (*setPV)(int newPV);
    int PV;
} classSource;

class class_init() {
    classSource cs;
    cs.publicValue = 15;
    cs.PV = 8;
    int class_getPV() {
        return cs.PV;
    };
    void class_setPV(int x) {
        cs.PV = x;
    };
    cs.getPV = class_getPV;
    cs.setPV = class_setPV;
    class *c = (class*)(&cs);
    return *c;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    class c = class_init();
    c.setPV(3452);
    //printf("%d", c.publicValue);
    printf("%d", c.getPV());
    return 0;
}
```

I presume that it might have something to do with using the initializer to add the getter and setter methods to the struct, as those might overwrite memory.

Is what I am doing undefined behavior? Is there a way to fix this?

**EDIT:** With the help of the answer below, I have re-written the code. In case anyone wants to see the implementation, below is the revised code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int pub;
} class;

typedef struct {
    class public;
    int PV;
} classSource;

int class_getPV(class *c) {
    return ((classSource*)c)->PV;
}

void class_setPV(class *c, int newPV) {
    ((classSource*)c)->PV = newPV;
}

class *class_init() {
    classSource *cs = malloc(sizeof(*cs));
    if((void*)cs == (void*)NULL) {
        printf("Error: malloc failed to allocate memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    cs->public.pub = 10;
    cs->PV = 8;
    return &(cs->public);
}

int main() {
    class *c = class_init();
    class_setPV(c,4524);
    printf("%d\n",class_getPV(c));
    printf("%d\n",c->pub);

    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @UnholySheep It is actually returning the dereferenced `c`. So the whole exercise with pointers is unclear to me. Probably to work around the incompatibility between `class` and `classSource`. John, why do you think you can return one instead of the other?

Comment: Your structs are *incompatible*. Maybe you can get away with the very first field, but not the rest.

Comment: You are assigning the function pointers with a nested function, which is non-standard C (no nested function allowed). So I don't really know the behavior of it, but would imagine these might behave as local variables and not be accessible from outside of the function.

Comment: C does not have classes: you are working half in C and half in C++.

Comment: @cup The OP is trying to implement something like classes in C.

Comment: try moving the `int apv;` source line in `classSource` definition to after the `void (*setPV)(int newPV);` source line so that the struct `class` aligns with the first part of the struct `classSource`. Also realize that when you return the `class` value, any of the struct `classSource` which you have changed is going to be clipped and removed that is beyond the end of the struct `class`.

Comment: Absolutely everything is undefined behaviour here. Casts don't work this way, nested functions don't work this way (actually standard C doesn't have nested functions at all, you are (mis)using a non-standard compiler extension), there are no closures, you cannot return an address of a local object. You can do OOP in C but you cannot fix your code. I'd say you need to unlearn what you have mislearned and start over. I recommend you get the source code of [X Toolkit Intrinsics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Toolkit_Intrinsics) and study it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three separate problems in your code.

1. You don't actually have a "*struct otherwise the same but without the hidden properties*". Your `class` and `classSource` structs have their `getPV` and `setPV` members in different places. Internally member access boils down to byte offsets from the beginning of the struct. To have a fighting chance of working, your code would need to have a common initial prefix of members between the two struct types (i.e. get rid of `int apv;` or move it to the end).
2. You're returning a struct by value, which automatically makes a copy. You've reimplemented the [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) problem: Because the return value has type `class`, only the members of `class` will be copied. The extra members of `classSource` have been "sliced off".
3. You're using nested functions. This is not a standard feature of C; [GCC implements it as an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions) and says:

   > If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function exits, all hell breaks loose.

   This is exactly what's happening in your code: You're calling `c.setPV(3452);` and `c.getPV` after `class_init` has returned.

If you want to fix these problems, you'd have to:

1. Fix your struct definitions. At minimum all members of `class` need to appear at the beginning of `classSource` in the same order. Even if you do that, I'm not sure you wouldn't still run into undefined behavior (e.g. you might be violating an aliasing rule).

   I'm somewhat sure that embedding one struct in the other would be OK, however:

   ```
   typedef struct classSource {
       class public;
       int PV;
   } classSource;
   ```

   Now you can return `&cs->public` from your initializer, and your methods can cast the `class *` pointer back to `classSource *`. (I think this is OK because all struct pointers have the same size/representation, and `X.public` as the first member is guaranteed to have the same memory address as `X`.)
2. Change your code to use pointers instead. Returning a pointer to a struct avoids the slicing problem, but now you have to take care of memory management (`malloc` the struct and take care to `free` it later).
3. Don't use nested functions. Instead pass a pointer to the object to each method:

   ```
   class *c = class_init();
   c->setPV(c, 3452);
   int x = c->getPV(c);
   ```

   This is somewhat tedious, but this is what e.g. C++ does under the hood, essentially. Except C++ doesn't put function pointers in the objects themselves; there's no reason to when you can either use normal functions:

   ```
   setPV(c, 3452);
   int x = getPV(c);
   ```

   ... or use a separate (global, constant, singleton) struct that just stores pointers to methods (and no data). Each object then only contains a pointer to this struct of methods (this is known as a vtable):

   ```
   struct classInterface {
       void (*setPV)(class *, int);
       int (*getPV)(const class *);
   };
   static const classInterface classSourceVtable = {
       class_setPV,  // these are normal functions, defined elsewhere
       class_getPV
   };
   ```

   Method calls would look like this:

   ```
   c->vtable->setPV(c, 1234);
   int x = c->vtable->getPV(c);
   ```

   But this is mainly useful if you have several different struct types that share a common public interface (`class`) and you want to write code that works uniformly on all of them.