# Is there a C and Python equivalent of Java's public and private?

Tags: java, python, c, private, public

I realized that in many languages I have learned includes the keywords `public` and `private`, and I also found out that Lua's equivalent to `private` is `local` which got me thinking if there is also an equivalent in C and Python.

So is there an actual equivalent of Java's `public` and `private` in C and Python?

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you would need the "functionality"?

Comment: One could think: you are actually asking TWO questions. Why not do exactly that, one for python, one for c?

Comment: Shouldn't a question be limited to one programming language?

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry about the question, C and Python are the most common languages I use, that's why I asked it this way.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Well, yes. But on how I want to format this question, I used 2 languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a naming convention for protected and private fields in Python:
A prefix of one underscore means protected, two underscores mean private. But this is not really enforced. More details here:
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/private-and-protected-access-modifiers-in-python

Everything not prefixed with one or two underscores is public.

In C, global variables and functions can be accessed from functions in other source files unless they are declared `static`. Not exactly the same as `private`, but C is not object-oriented so the concept of a class does not exist here.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can declare private members by putting dunders(double underscore) before member name, like this :

```py
class Sample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__private_mem = "Can be accessed only by member functions"
        self.public_mem = "Can be accessed as object properties outside the class"

sample = Sample()
print(sample.public_mem)
print(sample.__private_mem) # will raise an Error
```

But, I guess there is no such thing in C language as it is not object oriented.

Comment: 1. The convention requires only one underscore. Names with double underscores are subject to name mangling. 2. It's only a convention that names with an underscore **should** be used privately. They are not technically declared private in any way. 3. Due to the name mangling the attribute will be `sample._Sample__private_mem`.

Comment: Putting dunders before an attribute doesn't make it private, it just changes it's name to something that make it look like you really shouldn't touch it (name mangling). It's very similar to the C-way of making private members (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672015/hiding-members-in-a-c-struct). It's true that C is not object-oriented but you can make it work in a object-oriented way.

Comment: @Klaus D. you can see here for private members and methods in python: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/private-methods-in-python/
As far as C language is concerned so it is not based on OOP thus there is no such concept of classes.

Comment: You might want to read the article again. Quote: *"In Python, there is no existence of Private methods"*

Comment: oh yes, I got it, Thanks!!!

Comment: You should update your answer.